# Facing task Timeout Error while dag parsing in Airflow version 2.2.5

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I am hitting the task timeout error with `Airflow Version 2.2.5/Composer 2.0.15`. The same code is running absolutely fine in `Airflow version2.2.3 /Composer Version 1.18.0`

Error Message :

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 256, in __new__
    if canonical_member._value_ == enum_member._value_:
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 37, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: DagBag import timeout for /home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_dag.py after 30.0s.
Please take a look at these docs to improve your DAG import time:
* https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code
* https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/best-practices.html#reducing-dag-complexity, PID: 1827
```

As per the documentation or the links in error message about Top Level Python code.
We have a framework in place for Dags and tasks.

main_folder

|___ dags

|___ tasks

|___ libs

a) All the main dag files are in dags folder

b) Actual functions or queries (from PythonOperator functions/ Sql Queries) are placed in *.py files under tasks folder

c) Common functionalities are placed in python files in libs folder.

Providing basic dag structure here:

```
# Import libraries and functions 
import datetime

from airflow import models, DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator, bigquery_to_gcs, bigquery_table_delete_operator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
##from airflow.executors.sequential_executor import SequentialExecutor
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

## Import codes from tasks and libs folder
from libs.compres_suppress.cot_suppress import *
from libs.teams_plugin.teams_plugin import *
from tasks.email_code.trigger_email import *

# Set up Airflow DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
    'on_failure_callback': trigger_email
}

DAG_ID = 'test_dag'


# Check exscution date
if "<some condition>" matches:
    run_date = <date in config file>
else:
    run_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    run_date_day = datetime.datetime.now().isoweekday()


dag = DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    default_args=default_args, catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1, schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL
)


next_dag_name = "next_dag1"
if env == "prod":
    if run_date_day == 7:
        next_dag_name = "next_dag2"
    else:
        next_dag_name = "next_dag1"


run_id = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

# Define Airflow DAG
with dag:

    team_notify_task = MSTeamsWebhookOperator(
        task_id='teams_notifi_start_task',
        http_conn_id='http_conn_id',
        message=f"DAG has started <br />"
                f"<strong> DAG ID:</strong> {DAG_ID}.<br />",
        theme_color="00FF00",
        button_text="My button",
        dag=dag)
        
    task1_bq = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        sql=task1_query(
            table1="table1",
            start_date=start_date),
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table="destination_tbl_name",
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'      
    )

    ##### Base Skeletons #####
    with TaskGroup("taskgroup_lbl", tooltip="taskgroup_sample") as task_grp:
         tg_process(args=default_args,run_date=run_date)
         

    if run_mode == "<env_name>" and next_dag != "":
        next_dag_trigg = BashOperator(
            task_id=f'trigger_{next_dag_name}',
            bash_command="gcloud composer environments run " + <env> + "-cust_comp --location us-east1 dags trigger -- " + next_dag_name + " --run-id='trigger_ "'"
        )
        task_grp >> next_dag_trigger
        
    team_notify_task >> task1_bq >> task_grp 
    enter code here
```

Can someone help on this on what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the dag/task timeout time does the trick.

Go to Airflow (Web UI), On the top bar navigate to

Variables--> Configuration --> [core] --> dagbag_import_timeout = <changed from 30(default) to 160>.

If using Composer, the same can be done through following steps.

a) Go to Composer service and select the composer to which the settings are to be modified.

b) Click on `AIRFLOW CONFIGURATION OVERRIDES` --> EDIT --> (add/edit) dagbag_import_timeout=160

c) Click on save

Comment: It can work, but keep a few things in mind - it can affect and delay all your core environment when you upload a new dag. 
this error appears when your DAG is don't writing best practices, you can use the suggestion from the error msg and read here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/best-practices.html# how to improve your DAG.